# Django rest framework browsable API filters backend not showing

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I can't get the browsable API to show the "Filters" button after configuring django to use the filtering backend.

According to the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#setting-filter-backends) all I need to do is add the following few lines of code into the site's `settings.py` file and the filters should automatically be in the browsable API's web interface, and I just don't see it there. I tried restarting the web server (I'm working with `./manage runserver`) and that didn't help.

**EDIT:**

I know there's another option to turn the filters on a view-basis, but I want to have them on for all views.

According to [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#setting-filter-backends), it should be enough to do only one of those:

> The default filter backends may be set globally, using the `DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS` setting.

or following:

> You can also set the filter backends on a per-view, or per-viewset basis

From settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

  <snip>

  'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
    'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
  ),
```

Following content of `pip freeze`:

```
(venv) mba15:server nir$  pip freeze | grep django
django-allauth==0.28.0
django-celery==3.1.17
django-filter==0.15.3
django-registration-redux==1.4
django-rest-auth==0.8.2
djangorestframework==3.5.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you either specified `filter_fields` on your `ViewSet` or set a `filter_class`?

```
class ArticleViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    filter_fields = ('category', )
```

or

```
class ArticleFilterSet(FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('category', )


class ArticleViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    filter_class = ArticleFilterSet
```

Comment: According to documentation, it should be enough to do only one of those. Specifically: "The default filter backends may be set globally, using the DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS setting. ... You can also set the filter backends on a per-view, or per-viewset basis" see http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#setting-filter-backends

Comment: This isn't about setting the filter backend, it's about setting the fields that are allowed to be used for filtering by your `ViewSet`. Unless you specify the fields (using either method above) you won't be able to use the filter form.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you Sir! Documentation seems to be a bit unclear here.

Comment: Agreed, the DRF documentation doesn't specifically mention that you need to do this. I guess it's a security thing on `django-filters` part to prevent unintentionally exposing all fields for your views.

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar issue - the `Filers` button was missing from Browsable API view.

`fields` (in `MyFilter.Meta`), `filter_class`, `filter_backends` was all set. Strange about it was the `Filers` button was present on other views.

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSetMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    filter_class = MyFilter
    filter_backends = (OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
    ...

    def list(self, request):
        data = {'foo': 'bar'}
        return Response(data)
```

The problem went away when I've put `'results'` to the returned JSON, e.i. `data = {'foo': 'bar', 'results': None}`. No idea why that worked.

Comment: I had the same problem with `results`.  I had renamed 'results' to 'data' in my response.  So to get the `Filters` button to show up, I had to implement: `def get_results(self, data): return data['data']`